# Pivot table times by a table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some code for a pivot table but I also want to times (x) it buy another table if it full into the criteria.

```
select *
from
(SELECT 
        year(dteOccupiedDate) as [year],
        moveincharge as type ,
        left(datename(month,dteOccupiedDate),3)as [month], 
        MoveInCharge 
    FROM dav.Gainshare where strTenancyType = 'LTO' and dteOccupiedDate between '2020-04-01' and '2021-03-31' and moveincharge is not null
    ) as s
    PIVOT
(
    count(moveincharge)
    FOR [month] IN (jan, feb, mar, apr, 
    may, jun, jul, aug, sep, oct, nov, dec)
)AS pvt
order by year
```

this code shows

```
year    type            jan feb mar     apr     may     jun     jul     aug     sep     oct     nov     dec
2020    Single          0   0   0       5       1       4       12      12      6       0       0       0
2020    Family          0   0   0       5       1       4       12      12      6       0       0       0
2020    Early-leave     0   0   0       5       1       4       12      12      6       0       0       0
2020    Re-house        0   0   0       5       1       4       12      12      6       0       0       0
```

they are 4 different moveincharge types when it fallin that type I want it X times by the

single (150)

family (200)

rehouse (130)

early leave (140)

I can also make these into a table if that make it better.
I want to see this

```
year    type           jan  feb     mar     apr     may     jun     jul     aug     sep     oct     nov     dec
2020    Single          0   0   0       750     150     600     1800    1800    900       0       0       0
```

fo example Type Single for July is 12 x 150 because single is worth 150 each and there are 12 in that month

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you want to do.

Comment: What is your question here? You haven't asked one. What isn't working about the SQL you have? Sample data and expected results, along with a question, will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I much prefer conditional aggregation over the bespoke `pivot` syntax.  This is easily accomplished with a `join`:

```
select year(gs.dteOccupiedDate) as [year],
        sum(case when month(gs.dteOccupiedDate) = 1 then v.charge else 0 end) as jan,
        sum(case when month(gs.dteOccupiedDate) = 2 then v.charge else 0 end) as feb,
       . . .
from dav.Gainshare gs join
     (values ('single', 150), ('family', 200), . . .
     ) v(moveincharge, charge)
     on gs.movincharge = v.ovincharge
where gs.strTenancyType = 'LTO' and
      gs.dteOccupiedDate between '2020-04-01' and '2021-03-31' and 
      gs.moveincharge is not null
group by year(gs.dteOccupiedDate);
```

Note:  This will return two rows -- one for 2020 and one for 2021.  That is what your query does.  You might want to remove the `group by` and the `year` from the `select`.

Comment: how would u do it as a pivot if you know just want to know now

Comment: Or how would I and a total to the end right or at the bottom

Comment: @SQL_Noob . . . I wouldn't do it using `pivot`.  But you could do it by putting the `join` in the subquery and then pivoting off the charge.